# regex in java to split a comma separated string but ignore comma between double quotes

Tags: java, regex

My regex is failing to handle below **a)** but passes **b)** I have to handle the situation where comma is not followed by ".

The regex I used is:-

```
,(?=(?:[^\\\"]*\\\"[^\\\"]*\\\")*[^\\\"]*$) 

a) clean lname,,GandtTe,,:,.{}[]()~^*"@#$%&!\/'><;Gandt,Terry,L,,F,S,,7901 W Denver Ave,

b) 02, ,3006,101791106,,Lantz,Jon,Dow,,F,Unknown,,\"3301, Kntario Ave\",,,Kelando,5546215,FL,32806,,United States,,,,,,test@gmail.com,2306988547,19931325,20150825,Hourly
```

Comment: @anubhava could you please look into this problem.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to parse a CSV file. Why not use an actual CSV parser for that?

Comment: To go along with Thomas's comment, if your CSV file is large, regex is not an efficient way to handle it.  Better to parse it.